# shared_link null on file share api box node js sdk

Tags: node.js, box, file-sharing

I'm getting shared_link null by using box api https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#get-shared-link
Unbale to figure out that where am I doing?
Here is my code

```
function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
    console.log("requestCallback");
}

var accessToken = 'tvXSjyJM3XDh0YWss72ciYdXDtFNQeEh';
var r = request.put({
    url: 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/205773246434?fields=shared_link',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
}, requestCallback);

var form = r.form();
form.append('access', 'open');
```

And getting in response of this

```
{"type":"file","id":"205773246434","etag":"0","shared_link":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used box-node-sdk and made sure the app was "user-enabled" and it seems to work.

```
var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx',
  CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx',
  PUBLIC_KEY_ID = 'xxxx',
  PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = 'xxxx',
  PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE = 'xxxx',
  ENTERPRISE_ID = 'xxxx';

var sdk = new BoxSDK({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    appAuth: {
      keyID: PUBLIC_KEY_ID,
      privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)),
      passphrase: PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE
    }
});

var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', ENTERPRISE_ID);

client.files.get('xxxx', {fields: 'shared_link'}, function(err, data)         {
  console.log(data.shared_link.url);
});
```

Comment: Hi, @kendomen
I'm using your code for file uploading and I'm unable to upload because client is not initializing. Always getting "Unexpected API Response [400 Bad Request]"

Comment: Did you authorize your app in the admin console?